Shooting video games
There is a video game called "Blood strike - fps for all". In that game everyone jumps off a plane then they land and pick up guns to shoot people and be the last one standing to win, but for a period of time if no matter how many times you die you can come back again and play, and also if you get over 8 kills or so they start calling you "god-like" (Astaghfirullah) but you can mute what they are saying and also the music. So is the game haram?
